# How to output the top twenty strings from a dictionary<string,int> which is in descending order? (1st year comp sci student)

Tags: c#

I have

```
    private static void outputDictionaryContentsByDescending(Dictionary<string, int> list)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
```

so there it outputs each string with it's integer value in descending order but only want to output the top 20. I can't figure out how to do it, I've though of using arrays but don't know how to put the values from the dictionary into an array.

Comment: list.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).Take(20)

Comment: Your instructor has taught you about dictionaries, Linq, lambda expressions, etc., but not trivial-by-comparison ideas such as counters?

Comment: Come on people, don't just leave bare code answers on homework-tagged questions.  Point the OP in the right direction, but don't do the work for him/her :)

Comment: May i ask what school are you going to?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is the first 20 items from `list.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value)` then what you want is to take a look at the [IEnumerable<T> extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19e6zeyy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  The specific one you want is [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  But in general you'll want to familiarize yourself with these methods as they form a very powerful base for querying objects and data.

Also, one *very* important thing to be aware of when chaining these methods together is the order in which they're called.  Each call appends to the last.  (Look up [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), and don't be intimidated by it because it's a *very* in-depth subject that even the best developers need time and experience to grasp.)  So, for example, in your case you want to `OrderByDescending` and then `Take`, but definitely not the other way around.  If you did it the other way around, you'd first take the top 20 in whatever random order they're currently in and then order those, which will yield different output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Take`:

```
list.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).Take(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Take(20)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to do this:

```
private static void outputDictionaryContentsByDescending(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
{
    foreach (var pair in dictionary.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).Take(20))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).Take(20)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just want to throw out that you should not get hung up on "what's the best way" as getting such hung up - especially when learning - can lead to analysis paralysis.

The answers above are very good and the "right" answer, but I want to offer just a bit of perspective. I'm about to write something that starts with the code you had and answers your question inelegantly, but answers it none-the-less. And I'm going to do it to illustrate this point:

Sometimes, it's best to do something in a way you know and you are confident will work than to try to find "the best way". If you have time to explore "best" by all means do so. And you should from time to time in order to become better.

But don't get hung up on it. If you wrote this and it worked, it would in most cases "pass muster":

```
private static void outputDictionaryContentsByDescending(Dictionary<string, int> list)
{
    int iHowMany = 20;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value))
    {
        if(iHowMany-- > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

Best code? No.

Works? Yes.

And for much you'll do as a programmer, that's enough. In 2, 3 years down the road, you may read it during a code review and cringe, but it worked, you're better and if you want to update it, you'll probably be more than capable then.

Comment: I think it would be better to break when you are finished, so: `if (iHowMany-- == 0) break else Console.WriteLine...`

Comment: It would be better to do a great number of things. With my current level of expertise, I wouldn't write the above code - I'd use the .Take method that is already explained in other answers. But I wanted to illustrate the above point, so I intentionally wrote code that would make most experienced professionals cringe. And I did it because I remember the times when I was learning knowing that I was doing it "wrong" but able to get results was more important. And once you do enough "getting results" you're able to start working one at a time on "getting it right".